# Docker and ARM64 - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

My net core 5 API project builds and runs perfectly on an ARM64 SBC running Armbian.
I have tried to get it to run in a Docker container but receive an error
'Could not load file or assembly ‘/MyAPI.dll’. The system cannot find the file specified. I think it must be path related but can't see anything obviously wrong with the Dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
# Get Base Image (Full .NET Core SDK)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Generate runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
COPY --from=build-env /app/out/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAPI.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw maybe because the of this

```
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

Should change to the

```
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app
```

And the entry point just change to

```
COPY --from=build-env /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/MyAPI.dll"]
```

The reason is the output folder `/out` but you entry point in the root folder so that's throw the exception.

Comment: Getting a different error now 
``` Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application '/app/AllValvesAPI.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
```